# Python: create graph based on degree correlation

Tags: python

I want to create a graph using networkx which has positive or negative degree correlation.
Like a graph for a social network or citations in academic papers etc.
Can you suggest some function for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about producing a visual graph (diagram) you could look at using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) to generate them.  I'm not sure if there is going to be a single function that will do what you want (not enough detail) but its a comprehensive library used in many projects to achieve complex graphing related tasks.

Comment: I have installed matplotlib. Can you tell me a specific function for my query. For degree correlation read this http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/cond-mat/pdf/0205/0205405v1.pdf